# Circular redirection in tweet link

Tags: bug, status-norepro, twitter

I clicked [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) on tweeter link of MY and got circularly redirected among two sites `http://twitter.com/#!/StackJudaism` and `http://twitter.com/stackjudaism`

Same happens for many (most?) of other sites.

---

Hmm, today the bug is vanished. Thanks to all for checking this.

Comment: It just takes me to http://twitter.com/stackjudaism. What browser are you using?

Comment: @HodofHod I use Chromuim, but I see that the issue is fixed (possibly on twitter's side).

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Answer (score 2):

If that's the case, then it's a problem with Twitter (or your browser), not with this site. Those are standard Twitter URLs, so linking to them is not the fault of Stack Exchange.

Comment: I understand that, I taught that possibly the link was not constructed correctly by SE which caused redundant redirections. Bugs happen because of unpredictable reasons, you know.

Comment: BTW, somebody upvoted, so I understand that I wasn't alone with this bug.